# When using CDI in Java is the default constructor necessary?

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi

I'm looking into the code-base of an open source project, [mamute](https://github.com/caelum/mamute) which uses CDI. In most classes there is a deprecated no-arg constructor **and** a constructor annotated @`Inject`.[This](https://github.com/caelum/mamute/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mamute/controllers/QuestionController.java) is an example class in the mentioned project which has used this approach. So my question is, do we have to have a no-arg constructor even if we have a constructor annotated `@Inject`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The linked class has the following imports and annotations:

```
import br.com.caelum.vraptor.Controller;
...
import br.com.caelum.vraptor.routes.annotation.Routed;
...

@Routed
@Controller
public class QuestionController {
    ...
}
```

I've found [this javadoc for the `Controller` annotation](http://www.vraptor.org/javadoc/br/com/caelum/vraptor/Controller.html).

```
@Target(value=TYPE)
 @Documented
 @Retention(value=RUNTIME)
 @Stereotype
 @RequestScoped
public @interface Controller
```

Note the `@RequestScoped` annotation here.

The request scope is a normal scope (as well as application, session and conversation scopes) and JBoss Weld uses client proxies for normal scoped beans. To be able to create proxies Weld needs the following:

> The following Java types cannot be proxied by the container:
>
> - classes which don't have a non-private constructor with no parameters, and
> - ...

Source: [Weld - CDI Reference Implementation, 4.9. Client proxies](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/2.1.2.Final/en-US/html_single/#d0e1464)

In other cases you don't need the no-arg default constructor (see [`@Singleton` beans](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/2.1.2.Final/en-US/html_single/#d0e2058)).

Further links:

- [CDI specification, 6.3. Normal scopes and pseudo-scopes](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.1/cdi-spec.html#normal_scope)
- [AS7-5089: ApplicationScoped Object is instantiated twice](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-5089)